# Start querying on a certain row criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table which columns are post_id and post_msg. Now I want to query starting from a row that has a value of 3 in its post_id column. As a result of this query all the rows starting from post_id 3 (ASC) will be the result set.
How can i do this?

```
 post_id | post_msg   
   1     |   heheh   
   2     |   hi   
   3     |   hello 
   4     |   hoho  
   5     |   hayhay   
   6     |   harhar
```

from that table i want to query starting to a row that has a post_id that its value is 3
I know to use LIMIT but my requirement is really to use the post_id for some reasons.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
SELECT post_id,post_msg FROM table WHERE post_id >= 3 ORDER BY post_id
```

Comment: additional question, what if my post_id is a string? if in case...
thank you're answer is working

Comment: if string then enclose id in quotes - SELECT post_id,post_msg FROM table WHERE post_id >= '3' ORDER BY post_id

Answer (score 1):

you can try /// please correct me if I am wrong

```
select post_id , post_msg from 
table1 where post_id > = '@post_id_val'
group by post_id ,post_msg
order by post_id
```

What I am getting with question is that you want to show rows having post_id more then or equal to @post_id_val..
with ascending order of post_id..

Comment: thank you this is also working... but what if my post_id is a string?